# Wordpress category list without any line of code

Tags: wordpress

I have installed and configure wordpress on my server.

I have create some Posts and Categories.

What i want to do is to create a page with all categories. When i click on a category, i want to display all posts linked to this category.

Is there a way to do that without one line of code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**
If you are avoiding coding a plugin would be a nice solution:
[Documentation here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-from-category/)

**Option 2**
Using code there's a way of creating Page templates for the categories and getting customized results:
[Documentation here](https://artisansweb.net/display-posts-specific-category-wordpress-page/)

**Option 3**
You can use wordpress hierarchy to do it:

```
https://SITEURL/category/CATEGORY-NAME-HERE/
e.g.: https://mywebsite.com/category/cars/
```

I hope that might solve the issue :)

Comment: Okay so there are no native solution ? No way to do this without code or plugin ? Thanks

Comment: You can use wordpress hierarchy to do it:
https://SITEURL/category/CATEGORY-NAME-HERE/
e.g.: https://mywebsite.com/category/cars/

I'll edit my response and include this one.